# How to properly unwrap my mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv

Is there a way to automatically unwrap my character? If not, is there a tutorial or something?

Comment: Also, remember to apply *Location*, *Rotation* and *Scale* in *Object Mode*. *Ctrl-A*. It's a good idea to remember this when something appears to not work properly. This feature causes a lot of unexpected side-effects when forgotten.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unwrapping is a skill in and of itself. There really is no right or wrong. You have to judge that yourself.

I made a [fairly extensive tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9p9dYcvIzc&list=TL60v8BSV0JXXyGJ5pGk-vsEGJwr8p7PB4) on it, but here's a quick overview:

1. Figure out where to flow of the mesh and plan where to place the seams. Wherever you place a seam, Blender will "cut" the 3D model and try to flatten it. You want to make sure first and foremost that it will be able to split apart into even planes, otherwise you will get major warping issues.
2. Open up a UV editor and start placing the seams on the mesh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Mark Seam).
3. UV unwrap the model (<kbd>U</kbd> > Unwrap) and make sure it unwrapped the way you expected.
4. Tweak the seams until you're happy with the result.

After you unwrap a few meshes you'll get the hang of it, and you'll be able to unwrap quickly and cleanly.

Comment: If you are struggling, these steps will help, but I highly recommend the tutorial. Cleared up more that one question

Answer (score 11):

You can try using [*Smart UV project*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/uv.html#smart-uv-project)

1. Select your model and switch to edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>U</kbd>*> Smart UV Project*.

However, I suggest you look at some tutorials. [A search engine should be your friend here](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20uv%20unwrap), but here are a couple to start you off:

- [Blender Cookie](https://youtu.be/9Ha2rFR6qO0)
- [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1026/599)
- [The manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/uv.html#unwrap)

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be important to give some direction for what to do after following everyone else's answers and understanding the basics of UV unwrapping:

I have personally found that unwrapping Suzanne (the blender monkey) to be one of the best ways to practice this unwrapping skill at a medium level **without having to model a complex custom object yourself**

Doing this will allow you to immediately start practicing and build up confidence in UV unwrapping fast.

[image]