# Creating borders for flat models

Tags: texturing

I'm building a puzzle game and this is the method i'm using to create the puzzle pieces.

1. Create designs in illustrator.
2. Save the design as SVG. Import SVG to blender.
3. Save the model as fbx.

This is working well, but i need to have outlines around my puzzle pieces. For example, i need a piece to be black with white outline:

[image]

Please help me with this.

Comment: You could texture the model with a raster image of the outline (in blender), or you could try rendering an outline around them realtime in your game.

Comment: Texturing with raster image sounds simple enough!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a raster image to your model as a texture:

Probably the easiest way to add a texture to your model is by dragging and dropping an image from a file manager onto your object in the 3D view:

[image]

Note that you'll also need to UV unwrap your object.

For simple 2D objects extruded along the Z (like the one in the above gif), you can probably get away with looking at your object from the top (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>) in edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>), and with everything selected (<kbd>A</kbd>), pressing <kbd>U</kbd>*> Project from view*.

For more detail, see

- [The wiki on UV unwrapping](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping/UV/Unwrapping)
- [The wiki on texturing](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures#Material_Textures)
- [How to properly unwrap my mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6755/599)