# How do I rotate an unwrapped model?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to follow several texturing tutorials and guides, but I already have a problem after Unwrapping. My model does not get unwrapped nicely onto the grid... how do I do that? Even rotating the model itself does not seem to work. So I'm kinda stuck. Pure beginner here, I also got major help creating the (Fire Blast) model, shaped like the image I want to use (I cut out the fire blast shape with Photoshop already)

My unwrap in UV/Image editor:

[image: screenshot of unwrapping]

[album with images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWsZ3.jpg)

Fire Blast I shaped after and which I want to add as texture:

[image: http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/5/51/Red_Charizard_Fire_Blast_PO.png/revision/latest?cb=20140405150547]

[image source](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/5/51/Red_Charizard_Fire_Blast_PO.png/revision/latest?cb=20140405150547)

I have no idea how to do this. And you know Youtube... you hardly ever get an answer, or even a reply when you ask things there.

Also, when I tried again I had the same issue, but I tried to work backwards (instead of unwrapping first, adding the texture file to the texture pane first...) but my object model went pink? That usually means a missing texture, but I fail to see how a just added .png can be missing when it also DOES show up in the texture pane.

Hope you guys can help me. I'm sorry to bother you with this.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. It looks like you should change way of unwrapping rather than rotating existing UV map. It seems that your mesh has thickness and in this case if you use U > unwrap you should mark seams first. Or you could use U > Project From View to unwrap according to the current view in the viewport.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh

Comment: You haven't unwrapped your mesh properly. Go to the front view in *Edit Mode* and press **U-->Unwrap-->Project From View** (since your object is flat) and scale the UV island in the *UV Editor*. Remember to apply rotation and scale first (in *Object Mode* press **Ctrl+A-->Rot&Scale**).

Comment: Ah thanks for the answers guys. I will try that out. Though Paul the object isn't flat? It was a box first, but I placed the vertices on the picture's shape, then did extrude, place vertices, repeat until I had the model. So it's the same thickness as a box.