# How to UV unwrap a christmas tree cookie

Tags: uv

Thank you for getting back to me.... Here is the cookie. I agree it is bad topology. I am not sure how to proceed with making a Christmas cookie any other way yet. I would again appreciate any advice. Here it is: [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ndzz3k1vse90g0/somethinglike%20that1.blend?dl=0)

Can anyone think of a better way to do this? I want this shape for a cookie. I thought about using it as an outside for a plane and shape it that way but I cannot figure out how to do it. Thank you for your help if any one could please let me know how to do this I would appreciate it

Comment: It would help if you show an image of what you have. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add more information and images to illustrate your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly unwrap my mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh)

Comment: Your problem is probably not UV mapping itself, your real problem is most likely bad topology. Modelling a cookie from a curve object doesn't sound like a good starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, a question; Why do you use so many overlaying faces? I was going to try and make your UV simpler for you, but after removing about 30 faces on the top side alone, I gave up and made a new one.

This one does not have the same bumps and such as you had on yours, but it's simple. No overlaying faces.

I'd suggest making a new mesh from scratch. If you want the level of detail you went for on your file, simply subdivide the mesh, and do as you will. But overlaying faces is not necessary, and it will bite you in the butt sooner or later. As you've probably experienced already.

Remember, keep meshes as complex as you absolutely have to.

If you do it as I did in in the picture below, you'll have a really easy time doing the UV and texturing.

[image]

Here is how you can easily unwrap your mesh:
[image]

EDIT: On request of the OP, here is how I made the shape of the object.
First, I made a new cube (SHIFT+A). I then pressed Z to go to wireframe mode and removed the bottom part of the cube (I could also have simply added a plane, thought of that later).
I then shaped the square to match the shape of the object the OP made.
After that, I selected two verts and extruded them with E a bit down. From there, I moved the verts to match the corners of the original object.
Repeat and repeat (Selecting the two newest verts and extruded them further down)
Making sure the verts were at the right place, I started removing the faces. After that, I selected 3-4 verst at a time and pressed F to fill a new face between the selected verts to make up the shape of the object.

Once the shape was all done, I went to the modifiers tab (The one with the wrench icon) and added a solidify and adjusted ut to give it a nice thickness. 
I then proceeded to apply the material to the object, giving it the original appearance.

I never did it, but you can then TAB out of edit mode, and apply the solidify modifier to be able to select the verst on the bottom of the cookie.

Done.

Hope this helped.

Comment: "Keep meshes as complex as possible"!? do you mean "simple"? Sounds like he had it as complex as possible. lol

Comment: Thank you for your help and the video! I was wondering if there was any way you could tell me how you make the shape of that tree without so many faces and edges. Thank you so much again - sorry to be a bother.

Comment: "Remember, keep meshes as complex as you absolutely have to." I was implying that meshes should not be any more complex than what is absolutely necessary. If I said "Remember, keep meshes as simple as you absolutely have to" it would imply that one should make meshes as complex as possible ;)

Comment: @laurenbell if you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as the answer :) Btw, if you wonder how I made the cookie, I just added a new cube, shaped it like the top of your cookie, extruded to complete the shape, cleared edges and faces overlapping on the X,Y coordinate, and filled it again into a shape that is easier to UV unwrap. Took me literally a bit over 2 minutes.

Comment: sure I will (: I just have to figure out how to do it. Thank you. May I ask how you shaped it? was it the knife tool? And if you don't mind could you also tell me how to clear it out of the rest of the cube out of the way? I would so appreciate it. Thank you very much

Comment: I'll edit my answer shortly, so you'll find it at the end of my answer in a few minutes :)

Comment: Thank you so much! May I ask which tool you used to trace/cut the mesh out? I am going to start with a plane as you had suggested. I apologize - I am still very new.

Comment: Edit mode to edit objects. Select some verticies to extrude from (Extrude is almost the same as duplicating). 

I never cut the mesh. I simply moved the verticies to where I wanted them. When I deleted the faces as mentioned, I selected the faces I wanted to remove, pressed X and selected "Faces" to remove them.

Comment: I cannot chat otherwise I would move it there since it says to...sorry. I was wondering if when you get a chance if you could make a video of changing the faces sometime. I am trying so hard to learn how to do this, and I am still confused by it Thank you again very much

Comment: I'd advise you to follow these videos. His video tutorials on Blender are awesome and easy to follow, and he can explain this better than I can probably. He has a tutorial for pretty much every basic Blender action, so check out his videos (No promotion intended, but his videos are great) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS