# How do I change my model to work properly with UV Unwrap?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I created a character and now I want to texture it.

It was going well until I tried to add texture on sunglasses.

I open the **UV Image Editor**, after I unwraped the sunglasses and I am getting only a dot. Please take a look as shown in the picture below:

[image: Here is what happen]

Comment: Unwrap isn't broken, it's just made wrong, probably without assigning seams to let the mesh to be unfold. So now all the geometry of the sunglasses corresponds to that dot in the center of the UV editor. You might want to take a look at some unwrapping tutorials on YT or e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the mark seam on your sunglasses, Please select the boundary edges one by one and than

Follow the menu as shown in image

[image]

Or hit Ctrl + E and select the **Mark Seam** from the menu.

After adding Mark seams, Please Unwrap again, Good luck :)