# How to attach a texture to the first object of an array?

Tags: modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-coordinates

I seem to have the opposite problem to others:

I created an object (cuboid).
Mapped an image (png) as texture (mapping=repeat, coord=generated, proj=cube).

Now I make multiple copies of my object (arrays), the problem is that the texture repeats as if the whole array was mapped by a repeated pattern of my image in world coordinates.

Instead, I would like the image to map each copy of the object in the arrays in its local coordinates, i.e. I want to see the same image on each copy of the object.

Any help appreciated.

Here are the viewport and render screenshots:

[image: Viewport and render]

Comment: For this you will probably have to unwrap your mesh or drop the array and just use independent objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [texture properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/properties/index.html), you will find an [Image Mapping panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/types/image/options.html#image-mapping) as well as a [Mapping panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/properties/mapping.html). In the Mapping panel, you want to select UV as the coordinates value.

[image: mapping coordinates]

You can then get better results by properly [UV unwrapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6755/935) your object to control which part of the image is used.