# Apply UVMap mapping on meta object

Tags: texturing, uv, meta-objects

I'm able to set UVMap mapping for standard mesh object like the cube, but I don't figure out how to do the same for a meta objcet like Ball, Ellipsoid, etc.

These are the step I follow:

1) Create the object

2) Convert it to a mesh object

[image]

3) Create a material and a texture and assign them to it

4) Go under texture menu, set UV for Coordinates

At this point the dropdown Map menu is empty and I can't set UVMap as value.

[image]

Furthermore I noticed that when I switch to edit mode the appearance of my meta object is different from that of mesh object. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Did you create UV map for the object after converting? UV coordinates menu in the texture properties allows a value if there's at least one UV map. The last screenshot is not clear, are those 2 different objects?

Comment: I'm not sure on how to check if an UV map has been created and how to create it if not.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh for one example