# Is there a specific way to unwrap a character model?

Tags: texturing, uv

Like let's say you either unwrap the whole character itself or separate the head and the rest of the body so you have two different texture to work on for better details? Or is it more of a self preference?

And another question is how do you unwrap the head and the rest of the body separately (the character is one mesh) without the uv layout overlaying with each other on the uv layout?

Comment: Related/ possible duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh/6757#6757

Comment: I think the main rule is: the more a model (or part of model) is considered important (from the final result point of view) the more detailed it should be.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to UV unwrap and they are all for technical reasons.

As you mentioned, the head might be separate so that it gets a different (larger) image than the rest of the body.

Another way is to have the head on the same texture file, but occupying a larger space.

You can also UV half the mesh with the other half mirrored and "folded under". This will look like you textured half the body, but it covers both sides. This is mainly to conserve resources, as with background characters or with realtime (videogame) characters.

You need to create seams to unwrap. To separate the head, you usually create a seam that goes all the way around the neck. Where the seams go, however, depends a lot on what the geometry looks like.

Once you unwrap, assign the textures. Mind that the texture you see is just for the preview, it wont show up on the render until you assign materials.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether or not your character will be seen without clothing or not, mostly. It's best to determine whether or not that is the case, then make your cuts based on that. Best spots I've found are from the top of the head to the base of the neck, or down the spine, which still works if the character is seen nude, because the spinal area is just a trench on most people. If they're not nude, their clothing probably covers up to their neck, and your unclothed upper body geometry will likely end there anyway.

Extrude into the mouth and draw your seams where your inner lips meet your gums, or right at the inner lining of the mouth.

If naked, For the rest of your body, your seams are going to start at your the top of your thumb, then go up the inside of your arm to your armpits. Depending on how your nude or topless character is going to be seen or the complexity of the skin texture, cut the back off at the side of the body under the arms, and keep the arms connected to the front of the body, while disconnecting from the back of the body. Or if the texture isn't that complex it should not be a big deal if you split the front and the back, then cut the arms off by drawing seams around the end of the upper arm. You can keep the legs attached to the torso if you want, draw seams up the inside of the legs down to the feet. Draw seams at the shoes or soles of the feet.