# My material is showing up correctly in the preview window, but not in rendered mode

Tags: texturing, materials

I am trying to get this wall to look like this material (screenshot taken from the preview window in the material editor):

[image]

But, it just shows up like this (the gray area is the part that has the material applied to it):

[image]

This what the nodes look like:
[image: **enter image description here**]

Why does the correct material show up in the preview window, but not in the rendered version?

Comment: Don't crop your images so tight that we cannot see the interface. Never evaluate the texture by the preview, use rendered mode. Did you unwrap the mesh? When you use images as textures the default mapping coordinates are UVs.

Comment: sorry, I changed it now. I also took that second image from rendered mode.

Comment: And you didn't answer the question. Did you UV unwrap the mesh?

Comment: I don't know how to, sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: Read [How to properly unwrap my mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh/6757#6757)

Comment: Thank you, it works now!