# How do I get my texture to only appear on the front of my object and not the back too?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

So I have an image of a soccer jersey, that I would like to insert onto my character but when I do so it displays it on the front and the back, How do I rectify this? I just want it displayed on the front

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use UvMap instead of generated texture coordinates.

Comment: ffeller that didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly unwrap my mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh)