# Cant add texture to imported model

Tags: uv, stl

So i've made a component in solidworks, saved it as stl and imported it into blender. Followed a guide to apply a jpg image on the surface of the model. I got it to work on models that i created from scratch in blender, but not imported models.

went into UV editing and the mesh from the imported model wont show up ontop of the texture image like it does with the models created in blender.

Any ideas?

---

i've only used blender for 2 days but trying my best to learn. [image]

Here is the mesh of the model i've imported. If i select the other model instead that i created in blender, it shows up as expected on the picture to the left.

Comment: How does the model and its corresponding UVs look like? As it stands this question is not answerable at the 
moment for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember 
only you have access to your scene, only you know your exact setup, 
settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please 
describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by some
[accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)
with the [edit] button under the question.

Comment: ...does it have a UV map?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh

Comment: You'd have to select all vertices in order to display the UVs in the UV Editor (...and I guess it's a mess). Try to unwrap the object properly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM Also your topology is pretty bad, depending on what you'd like to do with the model might be better to start from scratch using quads only, see: https://topologyguides.com/