# Texture Baking in Blender not working on my models

Tags: texture-baking

i got a models, with multi texture, so now i m looking how to bake texture in one image file to put the models in an 3D engine like unreal

So this my models :

- I create a new image
- I open the flow manager and i add the image for the selection
- i go to bake option and i lunch the generation
  but nothink come to me

This is a video of my attempt : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwfOIl9f-uc

what do u thing is wrong on my process please

Webologie :

[How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake)
[How to properly unwrap my mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh)
https://gamefromscratch.com/baking-blender-materials-to-texture-to-make-them-usable-in-a-game-engine/
i follow this video guide : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYvgFWEiNp8

Comment: If u want the blender files  : https://easyupload.io/jq7vn4

Comment: Hello, you haven't packed your images so we can't test with the current texture, but maybe your problem is that you have a lot of materials, so you are supposed to duplicate the Image Texture for each material, which is not convenient, plus I'm not sure about your unwrap which seems rather messy, so the best is probably to duplicate your character, unwrap it, give it the Image Texture, in the Bake panel enable Selected to Active and increase the Extrusion a bit, like 0.1, and bake again?

Comment: Hello, i can't edit my post :

so this is the full pack : https://easyupload.io/dlys75

the file blender is : johannaBakeTexture.blend

Comment: Hello so if i unrwap i lost all my texture models :

Comment: unwrap the copy, not the original  ;)

Comment: Ok so if i do that on the copy i can get this : https://i.imgur.com/ObbTBsy.jpeg

but now how i fix the  texture on the map ?

because evrytime i bake, the texture is dark

Comment: now you just need to bake the original onto the new one, give the copy a material with an Image Texture that will be the bake image, put the 2 objects at the same position, select the first one, shift select the copy, in the Bake panel enable Selected to Active, bake

Comment: when i use the Seleted to active, i got an error message : 

https://i.imgur.com/KrKWj2H.png

and i select my model (the good one for the bake)

i select the image  in flow view, i select the model in object mod and i selecte to activa in bake generation and i got the error ?

https://i.imgur.com/Ra3CMdV.jpeg

Comment: please share your file again, but this time pack the images (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Comment: i upluod the files here : https://easyupload.io/ic0ex7

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of materials in your current object, it will be much more convenient to use the *Selected to Active* bake mode:

- Duplicate your object, keep the copy at the same position as the original
- Unwrap the copy with the *Smart UV Project* mode
- Remove all the materials of the copy
- Give it a new material with an *Image Texture*, in the *Image Texture* create a new image texture that you'll call *Bake* for example
- Select the original object, shift select the copy
- In the Bake panel, choose *Bake Type > Diffuse*, disable *Constributions > Direct* and *Indirect*, enable *Selected to Active*, give a bit of *Extrusion* (0.1)
- Bake, check the result

Comment: Hello i do all the step, but somethings missing to me :

- u can see my video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drWZIC-MTD4

- i upluoad my model with all texture : 



One files blender  with all stuff :  easyupload.io/ic0ex7
Or a folder with all models blender and all textures : the full pack : easyupload.io/dlys75 the file blender is : johannaBakeTexture.blend

Comment: you need to keep the copy at the same location as the original, that said I don't know why we see the original become black towards the end

Comment: Also, as you haven't removed all the material slots in your video, don't forget to assign the new material to your object in Edit mode, or remove all the slots (on the right of the material list, down arrow > Remove Unused Slots)

Comment: Hello, 

ok i follow what u said to me, and works perfectly !

I make a video of all action i do in blender to make works !!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKtrekI-b4Y


thanks a lot
merci !!!

Comment: you're welcome  ;)