# How can I solve this problem, while baking a high poly to a low poly one?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I'm trying to bake textures to a low poly, and here is a glitch I can not understand:

[image: backed texture]

My **low poly** unwrap is **fully split**, and the **high poly** use **object** mapping (cube map)coordinate which is a small cube.

Developing with OpenGL, I could imagine it comes from a bad texture coordinate for this particular vertex, but how could I verify that in blender?

Thanks in advance.

**edit**

Here is the uv's:

[image: uv]

I've set The island margin of smart uv, to make sure no overlapping occurs, but the glitch reapears
.
**edit**

here is the .blend:

[image]

**edit**
Maybe theres a trick with **Object Mapping Coord**, or a bug.

I've tried with **generated** mapping, no problems, But I would have preferred object mapping, for uniformity across models.

Comment: You could open file with your mesh in Blender, select mesh, [enter Edit mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/introduction.html) and check if there are overlapping faces on UV map. See [instructions on UV mapping mesh](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1026/1245) for more details.

Comment: @MrZak: effectively, when I scale down the low polly unwrap, and put some space between faces, the glitch is gone. But the unwrap is done with seam at each side, and should normaly work without modification, maybe scaling up the model could help, I'll try. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of UV/Image Editor with mesh in Edit mode and all the faces selected ? Also if it's ok to have seams on each side you could use not manual unwrap method, rather then *Smart UV Project* (it just may be faster to set up).

Comment: There could be some hidden problems here; probably, materials aren't assigned in desired way, or still there's a face/edge taking zero area in UV map; as of now it seems that there's wrong mapping on the lowpoly (mapping of the highpoly isn't important). Could you upload problem part of the file to [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ?

Comment: @MrZak: ok done, I've also restart from scratch an even more simple one, but exactly the same problem arise

Comment: While it *is* possible to bake using *Object* texture coordinates, I'd recommend stick to using *UV*, taking into account that you assign seams on the mesh. And these seams *won't* have no sense since they aren't used by *Object* texture coordinates.Regarding to baking - I was able to [bake the texture](http://imgur.com/xEWnpKh), and I'm not sure for now why it didn't work for you.

Comment: The only thing I change is materials' assignment. I add 'brick' and 'roof' materials, **assign** them to adjacent parts of the mesh, select 'Material.001' and bake. See [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh) for details about materials' assignment

Comment: @MrZak: I'm under linux with an old radeon card, maybe it's a bug, I've tried to make a single object of the highPoly, assigning material per face, but not change. I've also tried to unwrap the highPoly to rerset default uv (overlaping ones) even if I do not use uv for texturing the highPoly

Comment: @MrZak: I've tried to use 'Generated' mapping coordinate, and the glitch disapears, but I would have preferred static foreign cube (object mapping) to have uniform size of details among different models, thanks for your time zak.

Comment: I can't tell how it'll work with old radeon card on linux of course; [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=635) you can download your file, which works *for me* (it's packed with textures), so you can press Bake after download and it should work. If it doesn't then yes, it's a bug. Good luck with project!

Comment: @MrZak: It worked once, then I got same results, even when redownloading your .blend. So it's a bug (radeon, or blender or some pixel lib of linux.

Comment: @MrZak: When viewport shading is set to 'Rendered', baking output is correct (very strange)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, the way to solve this glitch is to set viewport shading to `Rendered` while baking.

[image]

This is clearly a bug in old rendering engine which seems solved in new Rendered viewport engine.

Comment: Please add some more details for people who may have this question in the future.

Comment: I don't know much about blender source code, The OpenGL feature used in the rendered viewport are surely different from other simpler (and older) viewports. The Rendered Viewport and Baking are options surely linked in source code (I think they emerged at the same time), but without diving in source code, It's impossible to say more.