# my picture is just grey and white

Tags: color

I loaded a file and the 3d model is white. I looked at different hoping to find a preset that will give the model color but I couldn't find it.

I then went to UV/editing to put an image in, but there was no color either.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't added a material to your model. You need to add a material, create an image texture node referencing your texture, and connect it to the base_color of the Principled BSDF that appears.

The material can be added by clicking on the +New button above the shader editor (while the mesh is selected), or in the materials tab of the properties panel (on the right, its icon looks like a checkered sphere). You can add the image texture node by pressing shift-a and choosing texture>image texture.

If you want a shadeless texture in EEVEE, use the Emission BSDF node from the shift-a>shader menu.

Answer (score 0):

**Image textures** needs UV Unwrapped Object.
You have to UV unwrap it first!
Select the object an switch to `Edit Mode`.
Press <kbd>U</kbd> and unwrap it!
[image]

Now you have to adjust faces in UV Editor for desired result.
For more about UV Mapping refer [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/adding-uv-mapping-to-mesh), [this](https://youtu.be/scPSP_U858k) or [this](https://youtu.be/Y7M-B6xnaEM)

> UV Mapping only works in Edit Mode